# C言語の配列の添え字[]内をchar型で指定するとコンパイルが通らないのってどうしてですか？

Tags: c

実行環境は下記の通りです

CPU ryzen 5 3600
OS windows10 64bit上のvirtual boxでUbuntu 18.04.5 LTSを起動
コンパイラ clang
オプション -Werror -Wall -Wextra

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    char s[10] = {};

    s[0] = 'a';
    c = 0;
    printf("%c\n", s[c]);
}
```

```
array subscript is of type 'char' [-Werror,-Wchar-subscripts]
        printf("%c\n", s[c]);
```

以下のようにキャストするか、またはcharではなくint8_t, signed char型で宣言するとコンパイルは通るようになります。

```
s[(signed char)c]
```

char型がsignedで定義されている処理系で128以降がオーバーフローする可能性があるためこういった警告が出るようになっていると推測していますが、それを確認するために参照すべきドキュメントが見つけられませんでした。
私の理解は間違っていますか？また、こういったことを確認したい場合、参照するべきドキュメントがあれば教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 参考までに、gcc にも同じオプション(`-Wchar-subscripts`)があって、`gcc(1)` には 'Warn if an array subscript has type "char". This is a common cause of error, as programmers often forget that this type is signed on some machines.' と記載されています。

Comment: gccのmanにあるんですね、検索不足でした。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Clang`のドキュメントはこれでしょう。

> [-Wchar-subscripts - Diagnostic flags in Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wchar-subscripts)
>
> ```
> Diagnostic text:
>                         lower bound
> warning: array section ------------- is of type 'char'
>                         length
> warning: array subscript is of type 'char'
> ```

他のエラーも含めてソースコードからの機械抽出らしいので、あまり内容は期待できませんね。

[Clang警告オプションとメッセージ一覧](https://yohhoy.hatenadiary.jp/entry/20150718/p1)

> LLVM/Clangコンパイラの警告オプション(-Wxxx)と出力メッセージの対応一覧表。Clangソースコードから機械抽出とのこと。
>
> - http://fuckingclangwarnings.com/
> - https://github.com/NSHipster/fuckingclangwarnings.com

---

@metropolis さんコメントのように、解説としては`GCC`の方に同じ警告があって記述があります。

[3.8 Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

> -Wchar-subscripts
> 　Warn if an array subscript has type char. This is a common cause of error, as programmers often forget that this type is signed on some machines. This warning is enabled by -Wall.

> 配列の添え字の型がcharの場合に警告します。これはエラーの一般的な原因ですが、プログラマーはこの型が一部のマシンで符号付きであることを忘れがちです。
> この警告は -Wallによって有効になります。

`char型がsignedで定義されている処理系で128以降がオーバーフローする可能性があるためこういった警告が出るようになっていると推測しています`

については、範囲外であるという意味では類似していますが、`オーバーフロー`というよりも`アンダーフロー`の方が相応しいと思われます。

この辺の記事から辿りました。
[Warning: array subscript has type char](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9972359/9014308)
[C++ Warning Array Subscript Has Type 'char'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58793298/9014308)

---

この記事によると：
[[C++] GCC/Clang/VisualStudio の警告をまとめているので紹介](https://zenn.dev/srz_zumix/articles/4c72e544b0034cc796da)

こちらのリポジトリでコンパイラ横断的にまとめられているようです。
[srz-zumix/awesome-cpp-warning](https://github.com/srz-zumix/awesome-cpp-warning)

資料/説明が無ければ他のコンパイラの仕様を参照してみてはどうでしょう？

ただし、類似であろうとの調査結果？/推測？で表になっていると思われるし、変わる可能性も考えられるので、注意はしておいた方が良いでしょうね。

Comment: gccのmanも見てみるべきでした！ありがとうございます

Comment: アンダーフローは浮動小数点型の話ではないのでしょうか？

Comment: 確かに浮動小数点数が対象の場合が多いですが、この「フロー」は「フロート(浮動小数点)」の略ではなく、このサイトの名前の一部でもあるように `FLOW`(流れ)です。アンダーラン(/オーバーラン)とも言います。スタック/バッファ/配列の添え字などを対象に使われます。[６．データ構造入門](http://www.akita-pu.ac.jp/system/elect/ins/kusakari/japanese/teaching/SoftTech/2007/note/6.pdf), [データ構造とアルゴリズムⅠB](http://agent.inf.kyushu-u.ac.jp/~yokoo/lecture/DA1_4B.pdf), [オーバーフロー/アンダーフローについてまとめてみた](https://qiita.com/YankeeDeltaBravo225/items/5efec3dea7f99e454dac), [メモリを壊してみましょう](https://www.uquest.co.jp/embedded/learning/lecture08.html)

Comment: なるほどっ！そういう用法もあるんですね、ありがとうございます

Answer (score 5):

K&R 2nd の 2.2 Data Types and Sizes に

> Whether plain `char`s are signed or unsigned is machine-dependent, but printable charactoers are always positive.

と定義されています。つまり、`char`は符号付きの可能性もあるし、符号なしの可能性もある曖昧な型です。文字として扱うのであれば問題ありませんが、数値として扱うのは危険であり、それが警告されています。

[INT07-C. 数値には符号の有無を明示した char 型のみを使用する](https://www.jpcert.or.jp/sc-rules/c-int07-c.html)で説明されていますが、具体例として

```
char c = 200;
int i = 1000;
printf("i/c = %d\n", i/c);
```

というコードがあった場合、 `i/c = 5` もしくは `i/c = -17` どちらの結果にもなり得るわけで、コードとして正しくても、プログラムとしては意味のないものになってしまいます。

`s[(signed char)c]` とするよりは `signed char c;` とすることをお勧めします。

Comment: ありがとうございます、勉強になりました